# Video glitch, dashed horizontal lines, on Intel graphics

Tags: unity, video

Can someone account for the dashed horizontal lines in my window screenshot below?

Are these details sufficient? I run Ubuntu 14.04.1. The video on this ThinkPad T530 is Intel i915 (OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile). I'm using its built-in display plus a Dell 2408WFPb that is attached via a DVI cable and a Mini DisplayPort to DVI Video adapter.

This effect is usually transient. I mean, it lasts for a few seconds. Then it seems a redraw occurs which corrects the display. I think sometimes a whole screen is affected, not only one window. In this case they affected one window and I was lucky to get the screenshot.

[image: gnome-terminal window with a rectangle redrawn correctly, the rest overlaid with dashed lines]

Comment: in your GRUB (`/etc/default/grub`), what does your line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX looks like?  Does it has "nomodeset" in that line?  If not, perhaps edit it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"`?  This tells your kernel/motherboard to not load video driver and to allow your Ubunutu to take over the control of video card during the booting.  It might would solve that strange glitch.  In my scenario, it solved so many issues when it comes to AMD radeon video card.

Comment: I'll try it! Currently GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="persistent"

Comment: My grub is `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash nomodeset"` which completely allows my Ubuntu to be in full control of everything.  You see, once kernel get loaded up with necessities data, it'll refuse to "hand over" them to Ubuntu.

Comment: Is this a case of "video tearing"?